# How to animate blocks zig zagged linked by a line to be a straight line on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi I have to animate using Javascript or somme kind of library (or CSS, whatever works best).

I am more of a PHP coder and I am not a Javascript expert. I am not exactly sure how to explain what I need so I am going to try explain it visually by adding a (badly drawn) picture:

[image]

I need help in how I can proceed with this, whether you can tell me what terms I can search for on Google, links to articles, anything will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here a global list of what you can use to animate something (all of these combined with a scroll listener in your case)

- [Anime.js](https://animejs.com/) if you don't care about IE<11
- [Canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Basic_animations) also can be good option and has wide browser support
- [Keyframes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes) used with [classlist api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) to fire animation when it needed
- Sometimes you can just change src of image to gif (without endless animation in your case)

I recommend you to just using GIF here if you can.